# How to get a textarea element in jquery when the name is in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I am trying to populate multiple text areas with a single select button .
For my application I cant use anything else (esp id's)
All the textareas are dynamically created and are named in order tx1 , tx2 ... txn.

my code is like ....

```
var count = 13;
            for(var i=1;i<count;i++ )
            {
            var txtname = 'tx' + i;

            var txt1 = $('textarea[name=txtname]');


            var selTxt1 = $(this).find("option:selected").attr('text');
.....
```

.....

but `var txt1 = $('textarea[name=txtname]');` does not work !!!
How do i provide the dynamically created name of the txtaarea to the var txt1 .

Comment: `$('textarea[name="'+txtname+'"]');` - quote around txtname

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this -

```
$("textarea[name="+txtname+"]");
```